# react-native app freezes temporarily without activity in performance debugger

Tags: javascript, android, performance, react-native, freeze

This is hard to debug because there is no activity in the chrome performance debugger when this freeze happens. A ScrollView still scrolls so it's not Android that's lagging. On the other hand, the Perf Monitor still shows 60fps for JS and it does not freeze.

Perhaps it's something with asynchronous code not returning, although the synchronous code should just continue running. When I submit changes, other actions (like navigating back) are also blocked despite that whole flow being asynchronous as well.

If I try to touch things (like change a selection) while it's lagging, the app may crash with the following error:

`Cannot record touch end without a touch start.`

```
04-16 17:18:17.749  7065  7102 I ReactNativeJS: websocket connection open
04-16 17:18:18.538  7065  7102 E ReactNativeJS: 'Cannot record touch end without a touch start.\nTouch End: %s\n', 'Touch Bank: %s', '{"identifier":2,"pageX":144.79888916015625,"pageY":327.2443542480469,"timestamp":22079251}', '[{"touchActive":false,"startPageX":321.55340576171875,"startPageY":325.2271728515625,"startTimeStamp":22079180,"currentPageX":322.0527038574219,"currentPageY":346.2295227050781,"currentTimeStamp":22079251,"previousPageX":322.0527038574219,"previousPageY":322.2295227050781,"previousTimeStamp":22079248},{"touchActive":false,"startPageX":235.17337036132812,"startPageY":257.2802429199219,"startTimeStamp":22079203,"currentPageX":234.674072265625,"currentPageY":281.2802429199219,"currentTimeStamp":22079251,"previousPageX":234.674072265625,"previousPageY":257.2802429199219,"previousTimeStamp":22079248}]'
04-16 17:18:18.565  7065  7102 E ReactNativeJS: 'Cannot record touch end without a touch start.\nTouch End: %s\n', 'Touch Bank: %s', '{"identifier":2,"pageX":144.79888916015625,"pageY":327.2443542480469,"timestamp":22079251}', '[{"touchActive":false,"startPageX":321.55340576171875,"startPageY":325.2271728515625,"startTimeStamp":22079180,"currentPageX":322.0527038574219,"currentPageY":346.2295227050781,"currentTimeStamp":22079251,"previousPageX":322.0527038574219,"previousPageY":346.2295227050781,"previousTimeStamp":22079251},{"touchActive":false,"startPageX":235.17337036132812,"startPageY":257.2802429199219,"startTimeStamp":22079203,"currentPageX":234.674072265625,"currentPageY":281.2802429199219,"currentTimeStamp":22079251,"previousPageX":234.674072265625,"previousPageY":281.2802429199219,"previousTimeStamp":22079251}]'
04-16 17:18:18.572  7065  7102 E ReactNativeJS: 'Cannot record touch end without a touch start.\nTouch End: %s\n', 'Touch Bank: %s', '{"identifier":2,"pageX":144.79888916015625,"pageY":327.2443542480469,"timestamp":22079251}', '[{"touchActive":false,"startPageX":321.55340576171875,"startPageY":325.2271728515625,"startTimeStamp":22079180,"currentPageX":322.0527038574219,"currentPageY":346.2295227050781,"currentTimeStamp":22079251,"previousPageX":322.0527038574219,"previousPageY":346.2295227050781,"previousTimeStamp":22079251},{"touchActive":false,"startPageX":235.17337036132812,"startPageY":257.2802429199219,"startTimeStamp":22079203,"currentPageX":234.674072265625,"currentPageY":281.2802429199219,"currentTimeStamp":22079251,"previousPageX":234.674072265625,"previousPageY":281.2802429199219,"previousTimeStamp":22079251}]'
04-16 17:18:18.614  7065  7102 I ReactNativeJS: 'ws onclose', ''
```

So part of my question is; How can I debug performance besides Chrome debugger and Perf Monitor?

And another part is; Why can asynchronous code block the app and how can I prevent this?

Any other comments that may help are also appreciated

by the way I spent time to optimize everything that was slow previously so when it's not lagging it all works pretty fast.